# Tokenizing string from dynamic array into multiple lines in static 2D char array

Tags: c, arrays, tokenize, dynamic-arrays, strtok

I have a dynamic array that holds a string containing '\n' characters, so this string is made up of multiple lines. I'm trying to extract the lines and put them all into a 2D char array and I'm getting segmentation errors.

Here's my code:

```
    char *input_lines = malloc(MAX_LINE_LEN*sizeof(char)); 
    input_lines = extractInput(MAX_LINE_LEN, input_file);
    char inputLines_counted[lineCount_input][MAX_LINE_LEN];


    char *t = strtok(input_lines, "\n");
    for(i = 0; i < lineCount_input; i++) {
        strcpy(inputLines_counted[i], t);
        // printf("%s\n", inputLines_counted[i]);
        t = strtok(NULL, "\n");
    }
```

Upon creating the dynamic array, I use the `extractInput(MAX_LINE_LEN, input_file)` function to populate the `input_lines` array with a string containing multiple lines.

Here's the extract function:

```
char *extractInput(int len, FILE *file) {
    char tmp[len];
    char *pos;
    char *input_lines = malloc(len*sizeof(char)); 
    char *lines;
    while(fgets(tmp, len, file)) {
        // if((pos = strchr(tmp, '\n')) != NULL) {
        //     *pos = ' ';
        // }
        input_lines = realloc(input_lines, (strlen(input_lines) + len)*sizeof(char));
        strcat(input_lines, tmp);
    }
    return input_lines;
}
```

Why am I getting segfaults here?

Comment: count the number of characters between \n, to make sure MAX_LINE_LEN is big enough and remember it needs space for the ending \0

Comment: @AndersK for my assignment, the max line length is a given value and I've already declared it in the code.

Comment: yes but was is the actual length you have in your input_lines

Comment: @AndersK well yeah that would vary for each line

Comment: but i guess you check that in code you are not showing (extractInput)

Comment: @AndersK I've added it

Comment: doesnt it seem inefficient to first read them as lines, then put them together in one line to later split them again?

Answer (score 1):

The function call

```
    input_lines = realloc(input_lines, (strlen(input_lines) + len)*sizeof(char));
```

takes your current allocated memory block and expands it, if it can. you should check the return value of realloc, it may fail.

btw when you allocate memory in C, you always need to have space for the ending \0.

see what happens with this file

```
hello\n
world\n
```

The first fgets reads in hello\n into tmp.

you now do realloc even though it is unnecessary, input_lines is already pointing to a buffer that could hold the string

```
char *input_lines = malloc(MAX_LINE_LEN*sizeof(char));
```

now with your realloc

```
input_lines = realloc(input_lines, (strlen(input_lines) + len)*sizeof(char));
```

you do strlen(input_lines) + len so you make the buffer strlen("hello\n") + len long.

but the important thing you need to notice is the following line

```
strcat(input_lines, tmp);
```

you have not *initialized* the memory that input_lines is pointing to, it can contain anything even \0's so your strcat could potentially put the string anywhere in the buffer and cause the error you describe.

Either do a memset or use calloc when you allocate the buffer.

If you use realloc you should keep track of the total size that you have allocated and how much you are using of it, before you copy into the buffer check if there is enough room. If not, add a certain number of bytes to the buffer.

I also noticed you read from the file line by line, then you concatenated the lines together to later use strtok to divide them again. It would be more efficient to return an array of lines.

Comment: My goal here is to capture lines and words from  a file into a 2D array if possible, but I'm not allowed to declare static 2D arrays that are large enough to hold all the lines/words, so I need to get around this with dynamic arrays. Is there a simpler approach that you could suggest here?